# find the 'y' when we only know 'x' and 'z'?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
x sum y = z
```

how can i find the 'y'?

example:

```
5 sum y = 8
result "3"

5 sum y = 3
result "-2"
```

any idea?

Comment: try subtracting x from z (like this): `z-x`

Comment: Sum in Mysql is a group aggregation function and is not used this way,

Comment: @JohnD wow.. u are so smart.. or im too dumb lol, thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try subtracting x from z (like this): `z-x`

Comment: i know.. when i want accept ur answer, the web says "you can accept this question in 6 minutes", so im leaving for lunch.. and im planning to accept your answer after lunch, do u understand?